# How to add multiple SEARCH_PATHS in one line?

Tags: xcode, macos, configuration, configuration-files, build-settings

I am trying something like

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = " $(./xyz/abd/)" + " $(./xyz/efg/)"
```

with xconfig file in xcode for keeping one location for project settings.

But I dont know how to put multiple paths together? Can someone help me on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "/path/1" "/path/2"
```

Also, next time you don't know the syntax for a bit of `xcconfig` file, just go to build settings pane and use the copy command (Cmd-C) and paste it on your file.